# MERN : Cookie deletes after page refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, cors

The problem I am facing is that after I login, cookie is present in my login Response-header.

[Login Response-header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqSbs.jpg)

But after I refresh/reload my page I am redirected back to my Login page.

[Getting this error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG5GI.jpg)

[Error returned from my backend, which is stored in my redux state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZaMY.jpg)

Which is due to the this 400 Error response sent from my backend.

authController.js(Bacend File)

```
generateAccessToken: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken
            console.log(req.cookies)
            console.log("hi")
            if(!rf_token) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Please login now 11."})

            jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, async(err, result) => {
                if(err) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Please login now."})
                
                const user = await Users.findById(result.id).select("-password")
                .populate('followers following', 'avatar username fullname followers following')
                
                if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: "This does not exist."})
                
                const access_token = createAccessToken({id: result.id})
                
                res.json({
                    access_token,
                    user
                })
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    },
```

Server.js

```
const app = express()

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())


app.use('/api',authRouter)
```

refreshToken() action is being dispatched from here to log In user even after he refreshes the page or access token expires

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(refreshToken())
  },[dispatch])

 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={auth.token? Home : Login}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

authActions.js (From which request is being sent to backend)

```
export const refreshToken = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem("firstLogin")
    if(firstLogin){
        dispatch({ type: TYPES.ALERT, payload: {loading: true} })

        try {
            const res = await postDataAPI('refresh_token')  // From here post req is being sent
            dispatch({ 
                type: TYPES.AUTH, 
                payload: {
                    token: res.data.access_token,
                    user: res.data.user
                } 
            })

            dispatch({ type: TYPES.ALERT, payload: {} })

        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({ 
                type: TYPES.ALERT, 
                payload: {
                    error: err.response.data.msg
                } 
            })
        }
    }
```

Therefore post request is being sent using this function

```
export const postDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
    const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
        headers: { Authorization: token},
        credentials: 'include',
  
    })
    return res;
}
```

authController.js (Backend file)

```
generateAccessToken: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken
            console.log(req.cookies)
            console.log("hi")
            if(!rf_token) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Please login now 11."})

            jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, async(err, result) => {
                if(err) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Please login now."})
                
                const user = await Users.findById(result.id).select("-password")
                .populate('followers following', 'avatar username fullname followers following')
                
                if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: "This does not exist."})
                
                const access_token = createAccessToken({id: result.id})
                
                res.json({
                    access_token,
                    user
                })
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    },
```

So the problem I want to be resolved is that, I doesn't want to be redirected to my Login page on page refresh but to be on the same page, which I refresh.

Comment: Links will be broken over time. I would like to kindly ask you to add your pictures to the question instead of linking them.

Answer (score -1):

Brought these small changes and it worked :)

Had spent my whole day on this thing :(

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:"http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}))
```

```
export const postDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
    const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
        headers: { Authorization: token},
        // credentials: 'include',
        'withCredentials':true
  
    })
    return res;
}
```